# Oracle tuning insert from a remote table using dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, bulk-operations

I have a remote table with 300 millions of records, I need to insert all the data in a table in my local database.

I try using

- [BULK COLLECT](https://hourim.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/tuning-an-insertselect-via-dblink/) clause.
- MERGE clause.
- PARALLEL INSERT

All the options take too much time.

What other options can I use to insert all the records in an efficient way?

I am using Oracle 11g in the remote and local database

Comment: well in my scenario i took dump of the table to local db then I insert them with a cursor loop with 2 column conditions , the good with the cursor with right conidtions will use bind variable method, ofcourse index was there too

Comment: Have you looked at data pump (export/import, optionally over a DB link)?

Comment: Transportable tablespace?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is taking dump of the table and load it locally then you insert the data. Normally I use a cursor loop with bind variable over bulk insert. However bulk collect is interesting you can use it.

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=expdpEMP_DEPT.log

impdp scott/tiger@db10g tables=EMP,DEPT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=EMP_DEPT.dmp logfile=impdpEMP_DEPT.log
```